# Fields with no nontrivial discrete valuation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am currently learning about DVRs and one can show that given a valuation ring $R$ of $(K,v)$ where $K$ is a field and $v$ a discrete valuation on $K$ that $K\cong F(R)$. I know that not all fields are fields of fractions of some nontrivial ring(trivial in the sense of $R=K$ or $R={0}$), e.g. finite fields. So there have to be fields with no nontrivial discrete valuation, e.g. finite fields. Now i was wondering wheter there is a different proof for showing that there is no nontrivial discrete valuation on a field besides showing that it is not the localization of a nontrivial ring and wheter this is simpler to show and if there are further examples of such fields besides the finite ones?
Thanks for answering in advance!
LG

Comment: If $K$ is algebraically closed then any non-trivial valuation is not discrete.

Comment: I have not learned about non discrete valuations yet, but i will google it. Thanks!

Comment: On $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\Bbb{C}(x^{1/n})$ the valuation $v(\frac{\sum_j c_j x^{j/n}}{\sum_j d_j x^{j/n}}) = \inf \{j/n, c_j\ne 0\}-\inf \{j/n, d_j\ne 0\}$ is non-discrete

Answer (score 2):

A simple type of argument is that of divisibility: if every element in your field has an $n$th root of unity (for some $n>1$), then suppose $x\in K$ has minimal positive valuation. Since $x=y^n$, we have $v(x)=nv(y)$, which is contradictory unless $v(x)=v(y)=0$. So you cannot have a nontrivial discrete valuation on such a field. This covers the case of algebraically closed fields, and also of finite fields since you have the Frobenius.

Answer (score 1):

You could be interested in the following article which I recently wrote with a colleague:
Rodney Coleman, Laurent Zwald : On Valuation Rings. It is available on Internet.
RC